# Using multiple scanners from one workstation

Tags: linux, usb, scanner, usb-hub

I have a lot of scanning to do and I'm looking to see how to best parallelize my efforts. Having multiple scanners running at the same time sounds to me like a no brainier. I'm trying to figure out how much this would cost to set up. It would be most convenient (and cheapest) if I could run multiple scanners off of the same powered usb hub connected to a single GNU/Linux workstation. However, it is not clear to me if this is possible. Has anyone done this?

Comment: You have two problems: hardware connectivity, which I _think_ should not be a problem with a powered USB hub; and the software configuration, where your scanner application may not allow multiple concurrent scans, though this _may_ work if you use a separate user log-in for each, or use command-line software, such as [`scanimage`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-scanimage/). I don't have multiple USB scanners to test either of these thoughts.

Comment: I was definitely looking at using scanimage for doing this as that is what my current bulk-scanning script is using.